# Django get domain.com/username

Tags: python, django, django-urls

url.py

```
 url(r'^(?P<google>\d{4})/$', twitter_auth.views.gu),
```

views.py

```
def gu(request, google):
    if request.method=='GET':
        mozz = request.POST.get('google', 'Fail')
        return HttpResponse(u'Name : %s'% mozz)
```

İ can't get google parameter only turn : Fail variable ?

Comment: You're question is very unclear. Please elaborate more.

Comment: Are all usernames four digits? Whether that's what you want or not, that's what your regular expression is matching (plus a slash at the end of the URL).

Comment: http://getmore-25205.euw1.actionbox.io:3000/1445/ i cant get it ? i need 1445 :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read `google` from request parameters. Instead just use `google` variable saved from the url and passed to the view:

Replace:

```
mozz = request.POST.get('google', 'Fail')
return HttpResponse(u'Name : %s'% mozz)
```

with:

```
return HttpResponse(u'Name : %s' % google)
```

Comment: http://getmore-25205.euw1.actionbox.io:3000/1723/ dont change anything :(